# How to ensure all PyTorch code fully utilises GPU on Google Colab

Tags: python, gpu, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I am new to PyTorch and have been doing some tutorial on CIFAR10, specifically with Google Colab since I personally do not have a GPU to experiment on it yet.

I have successfully trained my neural network but I'm not sure whether my code is using the GPU from Colab, because the training time taken with Colab is not significantly faster than my 2014 MacBook Pro (without GPU).

I checked and my notebook is indeed running Tesla K80 but somehow the training speed is slow. So I think perhaps my code is not equipped with GPU syntax but I couldn't figure out which part is that.

```
# install PyTorch
from os import path
from wheel.pep425tags import get_abbr_impl, get_impl_ver, get_abi_tag
platform = '{}{}-{}'.format(get_abbr_impl(), get_impl_ver(), get_abi_tag())
accelerator = 'cu80' if path.exists('/opt/bin/nvidia-smi') else 'cpu'
!pip install -q http://download.pytorch.org/whl/{accelerator}/torch-0.4.0-{platform}-linux_x86_64.whl torchvision

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.optim import Adam
from torchvision import transforms
from torch.autograd import Variable
import torchvision.datasets as datasets
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, TensorDataset
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

device = torch.device('cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
print(device)

# hyperparameters
n_epochs = 50
n_batch_size = 200
n_display_step = 200
n_learning_rate = 1e-3
n_download_cifar = True

# import cifar
# more about cifar https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html

transform = transforms.Compose(
    [transforms.ToTensor(),
     transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])

train_dataset = datasets.CIFAR10(
                    root="../datasets/cifar", 
                    train=True, 
                    transform=transform,
                    download=n_download_cifar)
test_dataset = datasets.CIFAR10(
                    root="../datasets/cifar", 
                    train=False, 
                    transform=transform)

# create data loader
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=n_batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=2)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=n_batch_size, shuffle=False)

# build CNN
class CNN(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(CNN, self).__init__()

        # (3, 32, 32)
        self.conv1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(3, 32, 5, 1, 2),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2))

        # (32, 16, 16)
        self.conv2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(32, 16, 5, 1, 2),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2))

        # (16, 8, 8)
        self.out = nn.Linear(16 * 8 * 8, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        out = self.out(x)
        return out

net = CNN()
net.to(device)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = Adam(net.parameters(), lr=n_learning_rate)

def get_accuracy(model, loader):
    model.eval()
    n_samples = 0
    n_correct = 0

    with torch.no_grad():
        for step, (x, y) in enumerate(loader):
            x, y = Variable(x).to(device), Variable(y).to(device)
            out = model(x)
            _, pred = torch.max(out, 1)
            n_samples += y.size(0)
            n_correct += (pred == y).sum().item()

    return n_correct / n_samples


def train(model, criterion, optimizer, epochs, train_loader, test_loader):
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        for step, (x, y) in enumerate(train_loader):
            model.train()
            x, y = Variable(x).to(device), Variable(y).to(device)
            out = model(x)
            loss = criterion(out, y)
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

            if step % n_display_step == 0:
                print("Epoch {:2d} Loss {:.4f} Accuracy (Train | Test) {:.4f} {:.4f}".format(epoch, loss.item(), get_accuracy(model, train_loader), get_accuracy(model, test_loader)))

train(net, criterion, optimizer, n_epochs, train_loader, test_loader)
```

Comment: I think this question is quite related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/51178965/6076729. 

Seems like Google might be giving only 5% of GPU usage for some users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems appropriate and I ran it on my MacBook, a GPU-enabled machine, and Google Colab. I compared the training time taken and my experiments show your code is optimized for GPU.

Can you try running this code from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48750199/google-colaboratory-misleading-information-about-its-gpu-only-5-ram-available/51178965#51178965) and see how much GPU RAM Google has allocated for you? My guess is you've only given 5% GPU usage.

Regards,

Rex.

Comment: I checked the RAM allocation, apparently I'm the less fortunate one :(. Thanks for your answer though.