# Runtime crashed even with loads of RAM left in Google Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to run a DNN in Google Colab as I saw they offer "Tesla K80", which would make my training way faster as I don't have a very good GPU in my  Laptop.

I ran the code and the runtime crashed. There was no error output, just a notification by Colab saying :

"Your session crashed after using all available RAM."

I looked up and I found this:

[Google Colaboratory: misleading information about its GPU (only 5% RAM available to some users)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48750199/google-colaboratory-misleading-information-about-its-gpu-only-5-ram-available)

I checked the available GPU memory using :

```
!ln -sf /opt/bin/nvidia-smi /usr/bin/nvidia-smi
!pip install gputil
!pip install psutil
!pip install humanize
import psutil
import humanize
import os
import GPUtil as GPU
GPUs = GPU.getGPUs()

gpu = GPUs[0]
def printm():
 process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
 print("Gen RAM Free: " + humanize.naturalsize( psutil.virtual_memory().available ), " | Proc size: " + humanize.naturalsize( process.memory_info().rss))
 print("GPU RAM Free: {0:.0f}MB | Used: {1:.0f}MB | Util {2:3.0f}% | Total {3:.0f}MB".format(gpu.memoryFree, gpu.memoryUsed, gpu.memoryUtil*100, gpu.memoryTotal))

printm()
```

and I got the output:

```
Gen RAM Free: 11.6 GB  | Proc size: 150.0 MB
GPU RAM Free: 11439MB | Used: 0MB | Util  0% | Total 11439MB
```

which means that I have enough GPU ram to train my model.

I tried restarting and resetting runtimes, I restarted the browser too. Nothing good came out of it. It kept on crashing.

Note: My training data file is 1.4gb, so I thought loading that might be using up the ram. So I split up my code, loaded the training data, and then ran the "check GPU ram" code again whose output was :

```
Gen RAM Free: 11.6 GB  | Proc size: 1.50 GB
GPU RAM Free: 11439MB | Used: 0MB | Util  0% | Total 11439MB
```

Still, a lot of RAM is left. And the runtime again crashed.

**How can I run my model training?**

(*following is my full code*)

```
import os
from google.colab import drive

drive.mount("/drive")
os.chdir("/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/GTAV/model")
```

## checking available GPU memory

```
!ln -sf /opt/bin/nvidia-smi /usr/bin/nvidia-smi
!pip install gputil
!pip install psutil
!pip install humanize
import psutil
import humanize
import os
import GPUtil as GPU

GPUs = GPU.getGPUs()
# XXX: only one GPU on Colab and isn’t guaranteed
gpu = GPUs[0]

def printm():
  process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
  print("Gen RAM Free: " + humanize.naturalsize( psutil.virtual_memory().available ), " | Proc size: " + humanize.naturalsize( process.memory_info().rss))
  print("GPU RAM Free: {0:.0f}MB | Used: {1:.0f}MB | Util {2:3.0f}% | Total {3:.0f}MB".format(gpu.memoryFree, gpu.memoryUsed, gpu.memoryUtil*100, gpu.memoryTotal))


printm()
```

## my model and train function

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tflearn
from tflearn.layers.core import fully_connected, dropout, input_data
from tflearn.layers.conv import conv_2d, max_pool_2d
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression
from tflearn.layers.normalization import local_response_normalization

###################################################
RUN_ID     = "model_alexnetv2-v0.9"
EPOCHS     = 10
VS         = 2000 #Validation Samples
WIDTH      = 160
HEIGHT     = 120
CHANNELS   = 1
LR         = 1e-3
###################################################

def alexnetv2(output=3):
    network = input_data(shape=[None, WIDTH, HEIGHT, CHANNELS], name='input')
    network = conv_2d(network, 96, 11, strides=4, activation='relu')
    network = max_pool_2d(network, 3, strides=2)
    network = local_response_normalization(network)
    network = conv_2d(network, 256, 5, activation='relu')
    network = max_pool_2d(network, 3, strides=2)
    network = local_response_normalization(network)
    network = conv_2d(network, 384, 3, activation='relu')
    network = conv_2d(network, 384, 3, activation='relu')
    network = conv_2d(network, 256, 3, activation='relu')
    network = max_pool_2d(network, 3, strides=2)
    network = conv_2d(network, 256, 5, activation='relu')
    network = max_pool_2d(network, 3, strides=2)
    network = local_response_normalization(network)
    network = conv_2d(network, 384, 3, activation='relu')
    network = conv_2d(network, 384, 3, activation='relu')
    network = conv_2d(network, 256, 3, activation='relu')
    network = max_pool_2d(network, 3, strides=2)
    network = local_response_normalization(network)
    network = fully_connected(network, 4096, activation='tanh')
    network = dropout(network, 0.5)
    network = fully_connected(network, 4096, activation='tanh')
    network = dropout(network, 0.5)
    network = fully_connected(network, 4096, activation='tanh')
    network = dropout(network, 0.5)
    network = fully_connected(network, 4096, activation='tanh')
    network = dropout(network, 0.5)
    network = fully_connected(network, output, activation='softmax')
    model = regression(network, optimizer='momentum',
                         loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                         learning_rate=LR, name='targets')

    model = tflearn.DNN(model, checkpoint_path="model-alexnetv2", max_checkpoints=1,
                        tensorboard_verbose=2, tensorboard_dir="model_training_log")

    return model


def train_data(training_data, model=False):
    X = np.array([x[0] for x in training_data]).reshape(-1, WIDTH, HEIGHT, CHANNELS)
    y = [x[1] for x in training_data]
    print("   >> Samples and Labels created.!")

    train_X = X[-VS:]
    train_y = y[-VS:]
    print("   >> Validation Set created.!")

    X = X[:-VS]
    y = y[:-VS]
    print("   >> Training Set created.!")

    train_X = train_X/255.0
    X = X/255.0

    if not model:
        model = alexnetv2()


    model.fit(X, y, n_epoch=EPOCHS, show_metric=True, snapshot_step=500
              ,validation_set=(train_X, train_y), run_id=RUN_ID)

    return model
```

## loading training data

```
import numpy as np
import time

start = time.time()
print("Loading data...//")
training_data = np.load("/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/GTAV/training_data-v0.3.npy", allow_pickle=True)
print(f"{len(training_data)} training samples loaded in {np.round(time.time()-start, 2)} seconds.")
```

## training model

```
print("-------------------------------")
print("Training model...//")

model = train_data(training_data)
#
os.mkdir(f"/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/GTAV/model{RUN_ID}")
os.chdir(f"/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/GTAV/model/{RUN_ID}")
#
#
print("Saving model...//")
model.save(RUN_ID)
```

Comment: "which means that I have enough GPU ram to train my model." I don´t see how you reach this conclusion, your fully connected layers will require a lot of ram. Did you check how much ram it used on your laptop?

Comment: @juvian  I don't know how much RAM it took but I did train my model in my laptop for 10 Epochs and it took 10 hours. I just thought Colab would take a lot less cause of so high-end GPU and high RAM. Following are my computer specs: 4 gb DDR4 RAM || Nvidia GeForce 130MX 2gb || 16 gb Optane Memory (though this won't be helping as far as I think, I'm just mentioning)

Comment: No sure then, seems like it should work. Maybe try kaggle

Comment: @juvian Thanks for your suggestion. But I don't know any way to upload my training_data (.npy file) to a kaggle kernel. I've searched a lot so far, still no good. I guess kaggle only supports datasets(.csv file) to be uploaded. Do you know how can I upload my training_data file?

Comment: I have seen npy datasets, it should work. Did you try to create a private dataset? If not, you can upload to somewhere and download it in the notebook, although it will take time if its large

Comment: @juvian I'll try that.