# Colab running out RAM

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory, kaggle, fast-ai

I've been working on kaggle's dataset Favorita Grocery sales. I'm trying to use the function add_datepart from fast.ai but when I invoke add_datepart, Colab runs out of RAM. Is there any remedy for this? Any way around this?

Comment: It's a bad idea just to share an entire notebook with credentials. I suggest you expire the API tokens in Kaggle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't share a notebook with your kaggle ID and api key in it. Other people can access your kaggle account with that.

Also, which runtime are you using? And what are your results from running the code in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48750199/google-colaboratory-misleading-information-about-its-gpu-only-5-ram-available/51178965#51178965)?