# Why that code snippet could not run at Google Colab?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, google-colaboratory

I use TPU which provides 35 GB RAM. Before I try to run this code snippet I had 20 GB free RAM.  But I could not run that code snippet because of low ram(it says more than 35 GB required) I used a 6 GB dataset. Why this code takes so much place? I used garbage collector and deleted the dataframe that I used before. What can I do to make that code working?

Gen RAM Free: 26.4 GB  | Proc size: 156.4 MB
GPU RAM Free: 16280MB | Used: 0MB | Util   0% | Total 16280MB

```
seed = 7
test_size = 0.4
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=test_size)
gc.collect()
model=KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=6,algorithm='kd_tree',n_jobs=25)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48750199/google-colaboratory-misleading-information-about-its-gpu-only-5-ram-available

Comment: Comments did not work for me and colab does not ask if I want more ram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data science workflows in Python tend to be quite memory hungry. For example, if your input data `X, Y` consumes 6GB, then the line

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=test_size)
```

will consume another 6 GB (each created subset is not a view into the original array, but a new array object with a new memory footprint).

Inside the `KNeighborsClassifier` other copies of the data may be made (e.g. the code in that algorithm requires input arrays to be contiguous C-ordered float64 arrays, and if your data does not meet that criteria a copy will be made).

In general, a good rule-of-thumb for data science workflows based on numpy is you'll need memory of about 4-5x the size of the raw data you're working with, unless you're very careful about preventing data copies.